# Jsdom.env to new JSDOM , migration

Tags: node.js, chai, jsdom

> Background

So, I have been following through a tutorial to understand the JS testing frameworks and have learned that to get the Web UI tested it is preferred to utilise the **JSDOM** library is it doesn't require the browser and brings the DOM which can then be executed in a Headless Fashion.

For the Assertion Library, I am using **Chai** and as a testing framework I have opted **Mocha**

> Test Case : I would like to test an html file by reading its h1 tag's value i.e. Hello World in this case and I would assert it to true.

```
import {expect} from 'chai'
import jsdom from 'jsdom'
import fs from 'fs'

describe('index.html', () => { // eslint-disable-line
  it('should say hello' , () => { // eslint-disable-line
    const index = fs.readFileSync('./src/index.html', 'utf-8')
    jsdom.env(index, function (err, window) { // eslint-disable-line
      const h1 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]
      expect(h1.innerHTML).to.equal('Hello World!')
      window.close()
    })
  })
})
```

This would work fine for an older version of **JSDOM** package but as I have checked the JSDOM docs i.e. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom the new way of doing this is JSDOM constructor.

So, how can I migrate this test case to adhere with the updated style of JSDOM library.

Comment: I would suggest switching to [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html), as it is basically Mocha + Chai + JSDOM pre-configured for you.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your recommendation, but right now I would like to understand the basic stuff in pieces and then would use a scaffolding Testing Framework like Jest. I would be great if you can help me with the newer syntax of JSDOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I have managed to get my test case up and running.

```
describe('index.html', () => { // eslint-disable-line
  it('should say hello' , (done) => { // eslint-disable-line
    const options = { }
    JSDOM.fromFile('./src/index.html', options).then(dom => {
      const h1 = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]
      expect(h1.innerHTML).to.equal('Hello World!')
      done()
    }).catch(done)
  })
})
```